# how to make id unique to call show hide method on each id click in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How can I access `seemore` button to all next `seemore` buttons? It only works for first one. How can I make it `-show` dynamic ids so it will work for all `seemore` buttons?

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass() {
        if (content.classList.contains("show")) {
            btn.innerHTML = "Show Less";
        } else {
            btn.innerHTML = "Show More";
        }
    }
    function showHide(shID) {
        if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
            if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
                document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
                document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**php:**

```
<?php 
$id1        =   $_SESSION['id'];
$sql        =   "select fname from User_registration where U_id=$id1";
$result     =   mysql_query($sql ,$conn);
$row        =   mysql_fetch_array($result);

$sql1       =   "select * from Job_post where u_id=$id1";
$result1    =   mysql_query($sql1,$conn);
$row1       =   mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$c          =   $row1[job_category];
?>
<div class="job" style="background-color:#E2F5D0;width:100%;">
    <div class="container" id="jobcontainer">
        <div class="row" id="jobrow">
            <div class="col-sm-12" id="jobcol">
                <h1 class="jobh"> Ciao <?php echo $row['fname'];?> </h1>
                <h3 class="jobh3">This is job_posting page. with description and budget
                    as per categories and sub categories. profile details are show here.
                    This is job_posting page. with description and budget
                    as per categories and sub categories. profile details are show here. </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="jobrow1">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                Description
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                Budget
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
$sql2       =   "select * from Job_post where job_category='$c'";
$resultr    =   mysql_query($sql2,$conn);

$index      =   0;
while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($resultr)) { ?>
        <div class="row" id="jobrow2">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h3 class="jobh33"> <?php echo $row4[project_name]; ?> </h3>
                <h3 class="jobh3">
                    <?php $row2 =   $row4['project_description'];
                        echo substr($row2, 0, 250);?>
                    <br>
                    <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">See more. </a> </h3>
                <div id="example" class="more">
                    <h3><?php echo substr($row2,250);?></h3>
                    <h3><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">See less.</a></h3>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <?php echo $row4['job_category'];?>:
                    <div class="jobh3">
                        <?php echo $row4['job_sub_category'];?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    Location:
                    <div class="jobh3">
                        <?php echo $row4['job_location'];?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3 > <?php echo $row4['budget'];?> </h3>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"> Fai I'Offeria </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use classes to do this. I am using jQuery because I don't know how to do this sort of thing with raw javascript:

```
<div class="group">
    <span class="name">Joe</span>
    <div class="moreinfo" style="display: none;">
        Stuf that is hidden about joe
    </div>
    <div class="evenmore" style="display: none;">
        Even more stuff.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <span class="name">Frank</span>
    <div class="moreinfo" style="display: none;">
        Stuf that is hidden about frank
    </div>
    <div class="evenmore" style="display: none;">
        Even more stuff.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
    <span class="name">Jitendra</span>
        <div class="moreinfo" style="display: none;">
            Stuf that is hidden about this OP
        </div>
        <div class="evenmore" style="display: none;">
            Even more stuff.
        </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ClickParent(ClickElem,ElemFind)
    {   
        $("."+ClickElem).click(function() {
            var GetGrp  =   $(this).parents(".group");
            GetGrp.find("."+ElemFind).fadeToggle();
        }); 
    }

// Find one level
ClickParent('name','moreinfo');
// Find another level
ClickParent('moreinfo','evenmore');
</script>
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qfqbmw2h/

Comment: i am using <a href="#" class="name">see more</a> instead of simple text <span class="name">Jitendra</span>

Comment: i am using <a href="#" class="name"> see more </a> instead of <span> but it will not work for that.

Comment: The principle is the same

Comment: <div class="group">
 <a href="#" class="name">How are you?</a>
 <div class="moreinfo" style="display: none;">
  Fine
 </div>
 <div class="evenmore" style="display: none;">
  Even more stuff.
 </div>
</div> it will not work now.

Comment: can you suggest how can i get ?onclick of Joe text is start from after Joe

Comment: What do you mean? That is what it does, the text comes after the name. Do you mean literally after it, like inline?